# My login screen is above the browsing window in IE, its cut off

Tags: html, css

I have a flask website with forms and I have a login page.  This login works fine on chrome and Firefox, however, it is cut off on IE.  You can't see it in the image, but there is no scroll bar.  The input form is literally half off the top of browsing page with no way to get it onto the page.  What's going on here?

[image]

Here is some of the css :

```
    body.login {
      position: initial;
      background: url('../../images/lock-1.jpg');
      padding-top: 0;
    }

body.login #content {
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
body.login .lock-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  body.login .lock-container {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 550px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
body.login .lock-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}
body.login .lock-container .panel {
  max-width: 300px !important;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
body.login .lock-container .panel img {
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
}
body.login .lock-container .panel input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body.login .lock-container .panel .btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
body.login .lock-container .panel .forgot-password {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #4687ce;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
<html class="hide-sidebar ls-bottom-footer" lang="en">
{% block body %}
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>Blassy</title>


      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/vendor/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/app/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">



    </head>

    <body class="login">

      <div id="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="lock-container">
            <h1>Account Access</h1>
            <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
              <img src="images/people/110/guy-5.jpg" class="img-circle">
              <div class="panel-body">
                  {{wtf.quick_form(form)}}  
                  <p>
                  <br><a href="{{ url_for('forgot_password') }}">Forgot Password</a>
                  <br><a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer class="footer">
        <strong>The Canonworks</strong> &copy; Copyright 2016
      </footer>
      <!-- // Footer -->
      <!-- Inline Script for colors and config objects; used by various external scripts; -->
      <script>
        var colors = {
          "danger-color": "#e74c3c",
          "success-color": "#81b53e",
          "warning-color": "#f0ad4e",
          "inverse-color": "#2c3e50",
          "info-color": "#2d7cb5",
          "default-color": "#6e7882",
          "default-light-color": "#cfd9db",
          "purple-color": "#9D8AC7",
          "mustard-color": "#d4d171",
          "lightred-color": "#e15258",
          "body-bg": "#f6f6f6"
        };
        var config = {
          theme: "social-2",
          skins: {
            "default": {
              "primary-color": "#4687ce"
            },
            "orange": {
              "primary-color": "#e74c3c"
            },
            "blue": {
              "primary-color": "#4687ce"
            },
            "purple": {
              "primary-color": "#af86b9"
            },
            "brown": {
              "primary-color": "#c3a961"
            }
          }
        };
      </script>


      <script src="js/vendor/all.js"></script>

      <script src="js/app/app.js"></script>


    </body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: Post the relevant CSS its most likely an issue with that. Also let us know which version of IE you are seeing this in

Comment: Will try to get CSS, but it's a huge file I didn't write.  Prob good exercise for posting to stack, tho.

Comment: Hmm another way would be to try and recreate the problem in a [js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post a link to that.